# Когда не ставится запятая в ССП?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, ссп

> В картине «Боярыня Морозова» Суриков запечатлел трагический эпизод русской истории () и несокрушимой духовной силе национального характера он придал осязаемые черты.

Увидела данное предложение и не до конца поняла, почему запятая ставится, ведь есть общий второстепенный член.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*В картине « Боярыня Морозова» Суриков запечатлел трагический эпизод русской истории,  и несокрушимой духовной силе национального характера он придал осязаемые черты.*

Обстоятельство "в картине"  **не является общим** для двух предложений, так как на картине можно что-то изобразить, а вторая часть сложного предложения ― это уже вывод, оценка. Поэтому запятая в ССП ставится.

Предложение **желательное редактировать**, например:

*В картине « Боярыня Морозова» Суриков запечатлел трагический эпизод русской истории,  **придав** осязаемые черты несокрушимой духовной силе национального характера.*

**Пояснение**. Союз И имеет обобщенное значение, и в данном предложении его конкретная семантика не выражена. Местоимение ***он*** также выглядит лишним.

Answer (score 1):

Трудно говорить о корректности постановки запятой в некорректно составленном предложении.
Во-первых, формально местоимение *он* замещает ближайшее к нему существительное *эпизод*, а должно бы относиться к Сурикову. Более того, оно тут лишнее, так как оба действия (запечатлел и придал) относятся к Сурикову. Во-вторых, автор хочет сказать, что Сурикoв придал осязаемые черты несокрушимой духовной силе национального характера **в картине**, а подобное утверждение, как указалa в своем ответе Sharon, некорректно (картина ничего не придает национальному характеру, она лишь отражает его). В-третьих, выражение "несокрушимая духовная сила национального характера" следовало бы заменить на "несокрушимая духовная сила русского народа" (не путать с выражением  "сила характера").

Вариант исправления:

**В картине «Боярыня Морозова» Суриков запечатлел трагический эпизод русской истории, осязаемо выразив несокрушимую духовную силу русского народа.**

А если уж очень хочется вставить союз *и*, то тогда так:

**В картине «Боярыня Морозова» Суриков запечатлел трагический эпизод русской истории и  осязаемо выразил несокрушимую духовную силу русского народа.**